# how to get 4 boxes centralized and a side by side?

Tags: html, css

```
    <section id="main-content">
        <div class="language-box html">HTML</div>
        <div class="language-box javascript">JAVACRIPT</div>
        <div class="language-box css">CSS</div>
        <div class="language-box php">PHP</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </section>
```

I'm trying to make this 4 box's become centralized and side by side.

I'm using this code, but it's not working as i hope:

```
#main-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.language-box {
    width: 279px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0mRj.png

Comment: Instead of float, try using display:inline-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove float, display items as `inline-block` and set `text-align: center` to the container.

```
#main-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}


.language-box {
    width: 80px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    /* float: left;
    margin: 0 auto; */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9k2ae5vv/

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear after float elements:
    #main-content {overflow: hidden}

Answer (score 0):

you must set width for your wrapper, and everything will be fine.

```
#main-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: calc(4 * 279px);
}
```

look [working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hdiur)

Comment: Older browsers can't use calc(), I don't see why you're using it for this situation, just use 'width:1116px;' instead.